# Append to table from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to get a table with data from JSON. My code looks like this:

```
var KrediteArray = $.parseJSON(data);
$.each(KrediteArray, function(index, item) {
    $('#UserKreditsTableBody').append($('<tr id="UserKreditsTr'+index+'">'));
    $.each(item, function(key, value) { 
        $('#UserKreditsTr' + index).append($('<td>', {
            text: value
        }));
    });     
});
```

`KreditArray` looks like this:

```
{
    "1": { 
        "Admin":"Luke",
        "Kapital":"100.000"
    },
    "2": {
        "Admin":"Capto",
        "Kapital":"100.000"
    }
}
```

My Table HTML Code looks like:

```
<table id="UserKreditsTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Name<td>
      <td>Betrag<td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="UserKreditsTableBody">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My Problem is that in the Table I do have 2 columns at the moment (I'm gonna add more soon, along with the data from the JSON). The Script only appends one `<td>` to the row, so I got one cell holding all information.

Could you please give me a hint?

Edit: Have a look at the picture [image]
<sub>(source: [666kb.com](http://666kb.com/i/d7gm1yh2pq13caeqm.jpg))</sub>

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The code seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/kd7d16de/

Comment: A Picture might be helpful: http://666kb.com/i/d7gm1yh2pq13caeqm.jpg | @RoryMcCrossan Now im absolutely confused, i dont get it why it is not working on my webspace - but thanks for you Help

Comment: As a hint, it's easier and neater to use javascript table creation functions like row = table.insertRow(0), then cell1 = row.insertCell(0), cell2 =  row.insertCell(1)

Comment: @LuckyLuke as you can see in the fiddle, that's not whats happening in a plain example. Please add your HTML and/or a working example of your problem to the question. Given your code at the moment there's no problem to solve.

Comment: I edited my first post with the Table, if i put that on friddle ist not working anymore. In Fact my HTML seems to be the problem.

Comment: Oh my godness it's so simple, i just forgot to close the `<td>` in the Table. I'm sorry guys and thanks for your help, you are awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try nesting another `each()` on `key` and then append each value to a `<td>` element.
Code should probably look like this:

```
var KrediteArray = $.parseJSON(data);
$.each(KrediteArray, function(index, item) {
    $('#UserKreditsTableBody').append($('<tr id="UserKreditsTr'+index+'">'));
    $.each(item, function(key, value) { 
        $.each(item, function(key, value) { 
              $('#UserKreditsTr' + index).append($('<td>', {
                text: value
              }));
        });
    });     
});
```